# Binomial Experiment

Tags: julia, binomial-coefficients

How do I use the Binomial function to solve this experiment:

```
 number of trials -> n=18, 
 p=10%  
 success x=2
```

The answer is 28% .  I am using `Binomial(18, 0.1)` but how I pass the n=2?

```
julia> d=Binomial(18,0.1)
Binomial{Float64}(n=18, p=0.1)
pdf(d,2)
```

How can I solve this in Julia?

Comment: Please post what you have tried?

Comment: I read the documentation of Distributions.jl and found the Binomial function that takes 2 parameters: n and p so it gives me Binomial(18,0.1) I dont know how to pass the success i want to know the probability

Comment: rand(d,2) gives me vector, not the probability.  What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Doc says i need to pass K, but the functions takes only 2 parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is the Probability Mass Function, aka the probability, that in a binomial experiment of *n* Bernoulli independent trials with a probability *p* of success on each individual trial, we obtain exactly *x* successes.
The way to answer this question in Julia is, using the `Distribution` package, to first create the "distribution" object with parameters `n` and `p`, and then call the function `pdf` to this object and the variable `x`:

```
using Distributions

n = 18  # number of trials in our experiments
p = 0.1 # probability of success of a single trial
x = 2   # number of successes for which we want to compute the probability/PMF

binomialDistribution = Binomial(n,p)

probOfTwoSuccesses = pdf(binomialDistribution,x)
```

Note that all the other probability related functions (like `cdf`, `quantile`, .. but also `rand`) work in the same way.. you first build the distribution object, that embed the specific distribution *parameters*, and then you call the function over the distribution object and the variable you are looking for, e.g. `quantile(binomialDistribution,0.9)` for 90% quantile.